# Alertdialog does not show

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous

I have class called JsonHandler with async task to connect to api and get json content. It's used in some activities but i cannot show alert dialog "Loading... please wait" Can you help me with this?

```java
public class JsonHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    JsonHandler(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Wait");
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          //Here program is connecting to api and return needed strings
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
       alertDialog.dismiss();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In Main activity:

```java
jsonResponse = new JsonHandler(this)
                    .execute("allowedVersion").get();
```

When I use alertDialog.show() in onPostExecute it will show up but too late..

Comment: You can try it this way, make the alert dialog a global variable as you have did, add the alertdialog code to onCreate, then just use alertdialog.show(); in the onPreExecute then alertdialog.dismiss(); in the onPostExecute

Comment: Mike if i will comment dismiss it will show, but still i think it doesnt work like it should. When I will tap Button [Check] I can see little Freeze, than I see alertDialog. I think it's too late :/. In doInBackground i am using URLConnection, maybe this makes problem? It looks like onPreExecute works when doInBackround finished :/

Answer (score 0):

`Alertdialog` is foreground thing so it can not be done in background method of `asynctask`. Do it by this way

```
private class JsonHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     AlertDialog alertDialog;
     protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourClasss.this);  
     }
     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void... params){       
            return null;
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            alertDialog.setTitle("The Process");  
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.success);
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.setMessage("All done!");  
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                Intent A = new Intent(DownloadActivity.this, Menu_activity.class);
                                                startActivity(A);
                                                finish();
                                        }
                                    });
            alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {          
                                  @Override
                                  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                            Intent A = new Intent(DownloadActivity.this, Menu_activity.class);
                                            startActivity(A);
                                            finish();
                                  }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: But when i'll do it in PostExecute it will show up when DoInBackground will finished. Is any way to show something like ProgressDialog or AlertDialog but Before DoInbackground will start?

Comment: simply use alertDialog.dismiss to close it in background.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out! :D.

I used everywhere to get data from AsyncTask .get(); by this GUI was freezed for a moment and AlertDialog couldnt show.

The best resolution which i found is to make Interface to get data from AsyncTask.